# select disabled

Tags: javascript, html

Я занимаюсь разработкой сайта для управления умным домом, и мне нужно чтобы:

- если в главном блоке `select` был выбран любой другой режим кроме `customMod`, все остальные `select` на сайте стали заблокированы (`disabled`).

Я знаю как по умолчанию заблокировать `select`, но как сделать указанное сверху не понимаю.

**PS**:
Если нужны какие-либо фрагменты кода или подробное описание чего-либо, я отвечу вам в комментариях к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ура! Я нашёл решение проблемы

Ответ был взят из https://searchengines.guru/ru/forum/945121

```
<select name="name1" id="name1"  onchange="if (this.value == 1) document.getElementById('name2').removeAttribute('disabled');

else document.getElementById('name2').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');">
<option value="">Выберите</option>
<option value="1">Тип 1</option>
<option value="2">Тип 2</option>
<option value="3">Тип 3</option>
</select>
<select name="name2" id="name2"  disabled="disabled">
<option value="">Выберите</option>
<option value="4">Тип 4</option>
<option value="5">Тип 5</option>
<option value="6">Тип 6</option>

  </script>
```